# count distinct hour from datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datepart

I am working with sql database, and I have problem. It is about public transportation, and I have table 'Traffic accidents' and column 'Time when accident happened' (datetime). I need to count how many accidents happened in specific HOUR, to realize what is the most risking part of day.
I know how to separate hour from datetime, but the problem is how to count and order..
It should be something like this:

***Time of traffic accidents***

```
 2011-03-05 07:40:00.000,        
 2011-03-07 01:15:00.000,      
 2011-04-07 19:00:00.000,      
 2011-07-23 11:00:00.000,        
 2011-06-22 07:09:00.000,
 2011-03-08 07:14:00.000,
 2011-02-02 01:26:00.000
```

***Order accidents by hour***

```
7h- 3 accidents,
1h- 2 accidents,
6h- 1 accident,
etc…
```

My English is not perfect, but I hope that I was clear enough :P
Thank you, Urosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
WITH T as
(
 SELECT '2011-03-05 07:40:00.000' Col1 UNION ALL        
 SELECT '2011-03-07 01:15:00.000' Col1 UNION ALL  
 SELECT '2011-04-07 19:00:00.000' Col1 UNION ALL        
 SELECT '2011-07-23 11:00:00.000' Col1 UNION ALL          
 SELECT '2011-06-22 07:09:00.000' Col1 UNION ALL  
 SELECT '2011-03-08 07:14:00.000' Col1 UNION ALL  
 SELECT '2011-02-02 01:26:00.000' 
)
```

Suppose T is your Table and Col1 is your datecolumn.

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour,Col1) as Hour,COUNT(DATEPART(hour,Col1)) as Accidents FROM T
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour,Col1)
ORDER BY DATEPART(hour,Col1)
```

Result:

```
Hour Accidents
1    2
7    3
11   1
19   1
```

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you very much, I executed query without a problem!

Comment: I can sleep now :) thanx again

Comment: Welcome @Urosh . Can you please confirm my post as answer. :)

Comment: +1, and you can replace `DATEPART(hour,Col1)` with `Hour` in `ORDER BY` and with `*` in `COUNT(…)`.